# State the parent function of $g(x)$ and the transformations applied to the parent function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given the function $g(x) = -3(x + 3)^3 + 6$, state the parent function that must be transformed to get $g(x)$ and state the transformations that are applied to the parent function.

Comment: Where did this problem come from, and what progress have you made yourself towards answering it?

Comment: What is the definition of parent function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the "parent function" is $f(x)=x^3$ and the transformations correspond with the -3 the +3 and the +6.

Transformations break down into two main categories: vertical and horizontal. Informally, horizontal transformations occur when you change the x-coordinate and vertical when you change the y.

So in this example, you can think of it as starting with $f(x)=x^3$ then:

- adding 3 to the x-coordinate (you are adding it to the x, not to the $x^3$). This shifts the graph left 3 units.
- multiplying that result by -3. Now we are changing the y value so it is a vertical transformation. Many books will break this into two steps, reflecting over the x-axis for the negative and stretching away from the x-axis by a factor of 3 for the 3. I think it's easier to think of it as multiplying all of the old y values by -3.
- Adding 6 to that result. Geometrically we shift up 6. Algebraically, we add 6 to each of the y values that resulted from the previous step.